# Error in .bib entry, "Too many commas"

Tags: bibliographies

The code for reference is this

```
@article{matcontcl,
 title= {MATCONT and CL MATCONT},
 author = {A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and  B.Sautois},
 year = {2006},
 journal = {Continuation toolboxes in matlab},
}
```

This is the error that follows

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: PropuestaInvestigacion.aux
The style file: abbrv.bst
Database file #1: biblio.bib
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and B.Sautois" for entry matcontcl
while executing---line 1049 of file abbrv.bst
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and B.Sautois" for entry matcontcl
while executing---line 1049 of file abbrv.bst
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and B.Sautois" for entry matcontcl
while executing---line 1090 of file abbrv.bst
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and B.Sautois" for entry matcontcl
while executing---line 1090 of file abbrv.bst
(There were 4 error messages)
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Off-topic: The use of then entry type `@article` for the entry at hand isn't ideal. Changing the entry type to `@misc`, and changing the field name from `journal` to `howpublished`, would be a good idea.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Don't use `,` (comma) as the separator between authors in the `author` field. Instead, use the keyword `and`:

```
author = {A. Dhooge and W. Govaerts and Yu. A. Kuznetsov and 
          W. Mestrom and A. M. Riet and B. Sautois},
```

In the `author` field, the comma is to be used only if you want to change the ordering of given names and surnames. For instance, one could rewrite the preceding example as

```
author = {Dhooge, A. and Govaerts, W. and Kuznetsov, Yu. A. and 
          Mestrom, W. and Riet, A. M. and Sautois, B},
```

Do note, incidentally, that I've inserted spaces between the initials of the authors Kuznetsov and Riet.

Comment: Don't we have a duplicate for this?

Comment: @Johannes_B - There have indeed been quite a few previous postings that raise the "too many commas" issue. However, those postings have tended to raise several points at a time, whereas the new posting is "clean" as it addresses just one issue. Anyway, I think I've now found a posting that may serve reasonably as a precedent.

Comment: We could also present this question, as it is *clean*, as the new dupe-original.